# How to get values in an array this way with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

From:

```
$arr = array(array('key1'=>'A',...),array('key1'=>'B',...));
```

to:

```
array('A','B',..);
```

Comment: Do you just want the first value from each of the inner arrays or all values from each array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relatively simple conversion by looping:

```
$newArray = array()
foreach ($arr as $a) {
    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
        $newArray[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Or, perhaps more elegantly:

```
function flatten($concatenation, $subArray) {
    return array_merge($concatenation, array_values($subArray));
}
$newArray = array_reduce($arr, "flatten", array());
```

John's solution is also nice.

Comment: Is there a built-in function to do this kind of job?

Comment: I believe there is no built-in function to do exactly this.

Comment: @Mask, Not with associative arrays.  Otherwise you could create a new array use one of several functions or the "+" operator to create a Union of the arrays.

Comment: Thanks, but my `array_map()` solution was wrong (only included the first element of each sub-array). Try the new one using `array_reduce()`.

Comment: Now that I read John's comment, only the first element of each sub-array might actually be what you want... Well, choose one version ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = array();
foreach ($arr as $array_piece) {
  $output = array_merge($output, $array_piece);
}
return array_values($output);
```

On the other hand, if you want the first value from each array, what you want is...

```
$output = array();
foreach ($arr as $array_piece) {
  $output[] = array_unshift($array_piece);
}
```

But I'm thinking you want the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
<?
$arr = array(array('key1'=>'A','key2'=>'B'),array('key1'=>'C','key2'=>'D'));

$new_array = array();

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $new_array = array_merge($new_array, array_values($value));
}

var_export($new_array);
?>
```

If you want all the values in each array inside your main array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function collapse($input) {
    $buf = array();
    if(is_array($input)) {
        foreach($input as $i) $buf = array_merge($buf, collapse($i));
    }
    else $buf[] = $input;
    return $buf;
}
```

Above is a modified unsplat function, which could also be used:

```
function unsplat($input, $delim="\t") {
    $buf = array();
    if(is_array($input)) {
        foreach($input as $i) $buf[] = unsplat($i, $delim);
    }
    else $buf[] = $input;
    return implode($delim, $buf);
}
$newarray = explode("\0", unsplat($oldarray, "\0"));
```